# $\mathcal{L}^1$ sequence question

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to determine the following simple statement:

If $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a measurable space and $u_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence in $\mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$ which converges pointwise to $u \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$ and satisfies $\int u_n d\mu \rightarrow 0$, then $\int u d\mu=0$

I think that this is true and my argument is that both $u_n, u \in \mathcal{L}^1$ meaning that they have a finite integral. Knowing they have a finite integral, I can use the DCT (dominated convergence theorem) to assure that $\int u_n d\mu=0=\int u d\mu$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$

However I am not sure if this is the correct approach

Comment: Are you sure you did not forget to require $u_n\ge 0$?

Comment: Anyway, your use of the dominated convergence theorem is unmotivated (indeed, Kavi Rama Murthy shows the conclusion you get is false). Who said that $|u_n(x)|$ is bounded by an integrable function?

Comment: Sorry, it was to determine true/false, I updated the text. However, in Kasi's example $u_n \geq 0$ so to me it doesn't look like it would change that the statement is false

Comment: No, Kavi Rama Murthy's example is sign-changing. If you assume $u_n \ge 0$, then the claim is true because of Fatou's lemma.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I see now, thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not true. Take $u_n =1-nI_{(0,\frac 1 n)}$ and $u=1$ in the space $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure.  Note that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for every $x$.

Comment: Possibly you should be explicit about what measure space you're talking about?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ok, so $\int u_n=0$ for all n as I understand it